# Edit CSS In Home Page

Tags: magento2, minify

I found a not `optimized CSS` in the body of the home page.
How can I edit directly this code?

**Magento CE 2.2.2**

http://prntscr.com/n5qggc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

I optimized the code, which i had previously entered.

[image]

[image]